# Using multiple layouts for list

Tags: android, layout, android-arrayadapter

I wanted to extend and ArrayAdapter so that the layout of the first row is different to the layout of the remaining items.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a addHeader for listView. you can use it inflate different view for the first item in the list.

```
listview.addHeaderView(customView);
```

you have to inflate your customView before adding it to the listView header.

Comment: I haven't gotten round to this as I've been tackling other parts of the project but I'll be sure to accept this if it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

it is simple enough
override `getView()` method of arrayadapter write an if condition for position 0

```
if (position==0) {
t = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
t.setVisibility(false);
// etc.

}
```

or you could add header to your listview `listview.addHeaderView(v)`

Answer (score 0):

You could have something similar to this

```
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if(position==0){
View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, parent, false);
}else{
View row = inflater.inflateR.layout.other_layout, parent, false);
}

 ......
}
```